# Sufficient condition on A for matrix product AA^T to be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inverse

$A$ is in general a rectangular matrix of size $(n\times d)$. The product $AA^T$ will be invertible when it is a full rank matrix, and I have read this happens when $A^T$ has at least $d$ linearly independent rows, "so that any point in $\mathbb{R^d}$ can be reached by a linear combination of such $d$ rows".

I wanted to please ask why this assures full rank of the stated product and what is the connection between its rank and this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When $A^t$ is injective, $AA^t$ is injective as well, because $x^tAA^tx=\|A^tx\|^2\not=0$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can see how $A^T$ injective means $\|A^Tx\|^2\neq 0$ (since $A^Tx \neq 0$ -- I have looked for what an injective matrix is and I understand it is that all its columns are linearly independent), but I cannot see why $x^TAA^Tx\neq 0$ means $AA^T$ is injective. Shouldn't the condition be $AA^Tx \neq 0$ (i.e. without doing the scalar product with $x$)?

Comment: If AA^t wasn't injective, then...

Answer (score 0):

**My own attempt:**

The product $AA^T$ can be thought of as a sum involving the column vectors of $A$, $a_i$:
$$AA^T=\sum_{i=1}^{d}a_i({a_i}^T)$$

Each of these terms is a matrix of rank one, and - as long as the vectors being added are linearly independent - the sum of rank one terms has a rank equal to the number of terms. We therefore need (exactly) $d$ of such terms for the product to be of rank $d$.